# How to emit socket.io event when a page is loaded in express?

Tags: express, socket.io

Sample code:

app.js

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(http) 
app.use(function(req, res, next){ req.io = io; next(); });

app.get('/about-us', routes.aboutUs);
```

routes.js

```
exports.aboutUs = function(req, res, next){
 io.of('/about-us').on("connect", function(s){
  s.emit('alert', 'Alert message');
 });
 res.render('about');
}
```

layout.html

```
about = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/about-us');
about.on('alert', function(msg){ alert(msg); });
```

My questions are is there a way to emit an event in socket io when a specific page is loaded? Also when I load 2 about-us pages and keep refreshing it seems like it keeps triggering the event exponentially.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to move the `.on('connect'` outside your handler. Node is adding a new event listener to `io` every time you make a request that matches `/about-us` (thus the duplicate events.) Your client javascript should (probably) wait until `DOMContentLoaded` before loading socket.io, connecting to the server `io` socket and sending a message `loaded` or similar to the server

Comment: Thanks Plato, but how will you trigger a socket.io event when you put the .on(connect) outside the handler?

Comment: Once you set a single `.on('connect')` socket.io will execute that code every time a client connects from a browser. The `.on('connect')` callback might receive some identifying data from the connecting client, so maybe you can construct and send your message immediately. Otherwise, set up a new event listener in node `.on('ginadLoaded')` and send a `ginadLoaded` event from your client, with the information you need, after your client has loaded and connected.